# use of array in php

Tags: php, ajax

How can I use array outside of the foreach loop so that it gives the same result?

```
 foreach($rows as $row){

 $s = array($row['sub_name']);
 $m = array($row['mark_obt']); 
 $show = array_combine($s,$m);

 echo '<br>';
 print_r($show);

 echo '<br>';

 }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.

For your question maybe you does to edit your onkeyup event like it : 

onkeyup="javascript:submitT('sub','myForm')" 

And edit your function submitT to use the id to find your element. You can to add with jQuery an onchange() event to check the length of sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
 $new_array = array();

 foreach($rows as $key => $row){
   new_array[$key]['sub_name'] = $row['sub_name'];
   new_array[$key]['mark_obt'] = $row['mark_obt'];
 }

 echo '<br>';
 print_r($new_array);
 echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one global variable ouside foreach loop and use the same variable in loop and assigned array to it.

```
$array = array();
foreach($key as $value){
  /*---Your Code---*/
}
print_r($array);
```